# Is there a way to still run on iPhone 5s with XCode 4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

If i try to debug an iPhone 5s on XCode 4 it will say:

XCode does not know how to run code on “arm64″ devices.

but, we still need xcode4 for temporary reasons. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

no, Xcode 5 is the first version of Xcode with a debugger for 64 bit ARM.

It might be possible if you take the debugger from an xcode 5 install and copy it to an xcode 4 install, but i can't say with any certainty if xcode 4 would be compatible with the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You cant debug iPhone 5s on XCode 4 . Apple may release a new version of Xcode soon. So you have to wait. But you can copy your app into device by using the organizer.